# Appcelerator memory management

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I just start using Appcelerator and I seek some information about it and I have read that Appcelerator has a huge problem with memory management and memory leaks. I would like to know if that is true before I decide to use it. Does Appcelerator have problems to manage memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one word: No

It's up to you. If you code clean and reusable, Appcelerator will not have memory leaks.

I also ran into memory problems. And in 95% it was my fault.

Appcelerator had memory leaks in the past. But since SDK 4.0 the most things are done and the SDK only gets better.

Give it a try and build the example apps to have a feeling how fast Appcelerator can be.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I will try it.

Comment: Best practices: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Coding_Best_Practices

Answer (score 3):

As a titanium developer for quite a while now I haven't seen any memory problems that are caused by titanium (except for some minor issues on Android with the older versions). Available memory on mobile devices can be relatively small and with Titanium, although they work hard on reducing this, there is always an extra framework layer consuming extra memory. It's just a matter of keeping this into account and writing clean javascript with as few unneeded variables as possible left open.

There is a great guide about Titanium, Memory management and Javascript garbage collection on [the Appcelerator Documentation website](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Memory_and_Finding_Leaks-section-29004941_ManagingMemoryandFindingLeaks-JavaScriptgarbagecollection) with good tips on how to monitor with Xcode as well.

There is also a must read article about this topic on [TiDev](http://www.tidev.io/2014/03/27/memory-management/) which you should also definitely check out!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the links.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an issue with the Titanium SDK leaking memory. Any issues have been my fault, not cleaning up a reference, not nulling, or forgetting to remove an event listener. The guides mentioned above are an excellent resource. As stated clean JavaScript keeps the maximum memory released.